# Best practices to handle documentation in Azure

Tags: azure, azure-functions, jira, azure-logic-apps

Cloud-Platform: Azure
Resource: Logic Apps and Functions

Hi everyone,

Kontext:
We have developed many Logic Apps and Functions in our company so far. We do not use a proper or standard methodology to handle the documentation of the user requirements and also the required technical documentation of these logic apps and functions. For technical documentation I mean all the documentation generated during the development life-cycle.

We use also Jira to assign the logic apps inside the company and also we are using X-RAY for testing. We have also Confluence for documenting our guidelines to development.

Question:
I would like to know what are the best practices to handle the documentation and very important how to keep it up-to-date?.
Is there an functionality in Azure, Jira or Confluence that we can control easily the documentation of our logic Apps and functions?

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the source code repository and the deployment pipeline that you are using to deploy the Azure functions and logic apps. If you are using GitHub or Azure DevOps, then you can make use of the GitHub/DevOps wiki to create documentation about logic apps or function projects just by creating readme files. Please review the following articles which will help you with the documentation

https://docs.github.com/en/communities/documenting-your-project-with-wikis/about-wikis

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/project/wiki/wiki-create-repo?view=azure-devops&tabs=browser